# Add select element onto a google map

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm trying to add two select menus with multiple options onto a google map but I'm not sure how to do so.  I did get the select element onto the document but it wasn't on top of the google map.  It created a white bar across the document.

Ideally I'm wondering how to simply implement a select menu on top of a google map with these menus:

```
<select name="buildings" onchange="updateBuild(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <option value="armory">The Armory</option>
   <option value="pillsbury">Pillsbury Hall</option>
   <option value="folwell">Folwell Hall</option>
   <option value="jones">Jones Hall</option>
   <option value="statue">Pillsbury Statue</option>
   <option value="wesbrook">Wesbrook Hall</option>
   <option value="nicholson">Nicholson Hall</option>
   <option value="eddy">Eddy Hall</option>
   <option value="music">Music Education</option>
   <option value="wulling">Wulling</option>
</select> 
<select name="transportation", onchange="updateTrans(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <option value="driving">Driving</option>
   <option value="walking">Walking</option>
   <option value="bicycling">Bicycling</option>
   <option value="transit">Transit</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does the code look like where you tried to implement this but it didn't work?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: why you removed your question? If it was answered, just mark answer as answer.

Answer (score 2):

you may add them as [map-controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomPositioning):

```js
function init() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 2,
    noClear: true
  });

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementsByName('buildings')[0]);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementsByName('transportation')[0]);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas">
  <select name="buildings" onchange="updateBuild(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="armory">The Armory</option>
    <option value="pillsbury">Pillsbury Hall</option>
    <option value="folwell">Folwell Hall</option>
    <option value="jones">Jones Hall</option>
    <option value="statue">Pillsbury Statue</option>
    <option value="wesbrook">Wesbrook Hall</option>
    <option value="nicholson">Nicholson Hall</option>
    <option value="eddy">Eddy Hall</option>
    <option value="music">Music Education</option>
    <option value="wulling">Wulling</option>
  </select>
  <select name="transportation"  onchange="updateTrans(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="driving">Driving</option>
    <option value="walking">Walking</option>
    <option value="bicycling">Bicycling</option>
    <option value="transit">Transit</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=init"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you.  I had no idea how to use google map controls!